# Upgrading to Linux kernel 3.13.1. Can't boot. A video driver issue?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, drivers, graphics-card

I'm using Ubuntu 13.4, kernel version 3.11.0-15-generic. I want to upgrade to kernel 3.13.1 to take advantage of the new multi-queue block layer. This is very important for me, since I am benchmarking SSDs.

I followed the instructions here on the installation: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-13-1-ubuntu/.

I then restarted. I get the following [screen](http://oi57.tinypic.com/jhbj9e.jpg) on start-up.

The link I used actually also says this:

> "If you’re using a proprietary video driver, you may need to re-build
>   or re-install to get it work with the new kernel."

So perhaps I need to upgrade my video driver? If so, how does one do that?

I found this command to check what driver I have: lshw -c video. Here is the output.

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Chelsea XT GL [FirePro M4000]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d4300000-d433ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d4360000-d437ffff
```

I then tried looking up updating or reinstalling the radeon driver, but I couldn't find anything. This makes me believe I am on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible ideas:

- install latest [fglrx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) (binary driver)
- switch to [open source driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)
- Try kernel 3.14, 3.15 or 3.12 if you can reproduce issue. Precompiled for Ubuntu can be found in [kernel ppa](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions are very much appreciated. It's been a while since I posted the original question, and I'm working on other things now, but when I get back to this project I'll try out your tips.